# UI-Router ng-class="$state.includes('name')" not working in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, ng-class

I want to use the abilitie of ui-router to test the active state in a ng-class

If I try this it does not work :

```
navTest.$inject = ["$compile", "$navbar", "$state"];
function navTest($compile, $navbar, $state) {
    var defaults = $navbar.defaults;

    var navTest = {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">' +
            '<div class="container-fluid">' +
                '<div class="navbar-header">' +
                    '<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">' +
                        '<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>' +
                        '<span class="icon-bar"></span>' +
                        '<span class="icon-bar"></span>' +
                        '<span class="icon-bar"></span>' +
                    '</button>' +
                    '<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">' +
                    '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">' +
                        '<li data-ng-class="{active: $state.includes(\'user\')}"><a data-ui-sref="user.List">Link 1</a></li>' +
                        '<li data-ng-class="{active: $state.includes(\'technology\')}"><a data-ui-sref="technology.List">Link 2</a></li>' +
                    '</ul>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</nav>',   
        replace: true
    };
    return navTest; 
}
```

Now if I add a function to test the active state in the "link" function
(of the directive) and I replace : data-ng-class="{active: $state.includes(\'technology\')}" by **data-ng-class="{active: isActiveState(\'technology\')}"**

```
link : function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    scope.isActiveState = function (name) {                 
        return $state.includes(name);
    };
}
```

Everything works fine but I don't understand why because the function does exactly the same thing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a scope thing but you don't want to use `$rootScope`; putting the following in your `link` function should be enough:

```
scope.$state = $state;
```

Comment: Dont forget to add the '$' to the 'scope' so you have
$scope.$state = $state;

Comment: I would not expose ``$state`` in the scope and use ``includedByState`` filter instead - https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.4.2/index.html#/api/ui.router.state.filter:includedByState. Example: ``ng-class="{active: ('my.**' | includedByState)}``

Answer (score 4):

That's because `$state` is not on your scope. What I recommend is that you add a reference to `$state` in your `scope` (using your link function). If you are likely to need `$state` in several places, I suggest you add it to the `$rootScope` using the run function of your module / application:

```
angular
    .module('yourModule')
    .run([
        '$rootScope',
        '$state',
        function ($rootScope, $state) {
            $rootScope.$state = $state;
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: it works fine. but why it is necessary to put the $state in the scope (or rootscope). Injection is not sufficient

Comment: Injection only inject it into your controller, directive, service, etc... Views are don't have access to them: scopes are the glue between views and controllers. So if you want to make something available to your view, you need to add it explicitly to its scope.

Comment: I understand wht you say but if I use $translate for example. In the "template" of my directive I can use it in an expression like {{lib | translate}} without binding it to my scope - And if I look at my app.js the $rootScope.$state= $state declaration in a "run" module was present. But my Directive has an isolate scope (scope: {...}). So how I can use the rootScope.$state ?

Comment: Filters can be accessed from the view, that's why you can use 'translate', 'filter', 'date', etc... If you have an isolated scope, then add $state to your scope in your link function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ui-router filters in template.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#filters-1

In your case:

```
ng-class="{ active: 'user' | includedByState }"
```